# Xamarin Forms Convert from Image to Base64 from Image Control not from file

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tobase64string

I am loading an image from the camera into an Image control. That works beautifully as shown below.

```
var photo = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { });

if (photo != null)
PhotoImageRear.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo.GetStream(); });
```

I sometime later need to take the images loaded into that PhotoImageRear control and convert it to a base64 string in order to post it to an API.

What would be the most efficient way of achieving that.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you can't extract the original image data from the Image control.  You need to either same the image data in memory or write it to a file if you need to access it later.  The CrossMedia plugin will create a file for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid this but seems like the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From shared code ,once you get the `photo`, you can use the following code to convert to **Base64** .

```
var stream = photo.GetStream();
var bytes = new byte [stream.Length];
await stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
string base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```